# Where to ask color-related questions if not in Photography?

Tags: support

I have asked a question related to technical details of the CIE Yxy diagram in **Photography,** and I was asked to go to *another* forum. However others have asked similar, and most of all, I don't see a "color science" related forum here.

So *where* to ask such questions if not here?

Comment: Do you have a link to the question you asked?

Comment: @MichaelC: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/108681/how-would-i-construct-the-cie-yxy-diagram

Comment: I suggest asking this question on https://meta.stackexchange.com rather than here, because solving that problem isn't really _about this site itself_.

Comment: I hope the "ask someone else" will not reach the last one. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There might not be a good place for such questions.  Stack Exchange doesn't have communities for answering all questions.  Graphics Design might be able to handle it as color theory in general is probably a bit more in their field, but it's hard to say for sure if they get that technical.  They might have a better idea where it could fit if not there too.  I'd concur that the question really wasn't photography related though as you are really interested in color spaces independent of photography.  If you had a contextual application to photography that you were trying to accomplish, it might be able to fit here ok, but just general color theory isn't really photography.

Comment: Actually today's digital cameras would not exist without color theory, and all the ICC profile stuff is hard to get without color theory. Actually I'm preparing graphics for a lecture, and I had to do them myself to get the require quality and style...

Comment: Which is why I said "color spaces independent of photography".  Modern cameras also don't work without semiconductors and understanding some elements of their behavior is significant for understanding sensor behavior, but that doesn't make questions about electron doping on topic unless it's specifically about how it applies to photography.

Comment: Color theory is a super broad field with a ton to it.  I love the field and having a four hour discussion on it with my art teacher sister is what actually convinced her of my standing as having an art education, but it also covers far more than what's related to photography.  Color theory questions related to photography fit well, but questions with no clear connection don't.  If there's a situation where plotting a color space is relevant the context would be important to how to illustrate it, but a general illustration doesn't have a connection.